# Let H be a subgroup of a group G. Prove that the following statements are equivalent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let H be a subgroup of a group G. Prove that the following statements are equivalent.

(a) For all $a,b \in G, (aH)(bH)$ is a left coset of $H$ in $G$.

(b) For all $a,b \in G, (aH)(bH) = (ab)H$.

(c) For all $a \in G, (aH)(a^{-1}H) = H.$

(d) For all $a \in G, aHa^{-1} \subseteq H.$

(e) For all $a\in G, aHa^{-1} = H.$

(f) For all $a\in G, aH = Ha.$

My attempt:

(a) implies (b):

I can show $abH \subseteq aHbH$ since $abh_1 = a1_Hbh_1$ but i can't show the other direction.

NEED HELP

(b) implies (c) :

Let $b = a^{-1}$

(c) implies (d):

For all $a \in G$, $ah_1a^{-1}h_2 = h_3$ and hence $ah_1a^{-1} = h_3(h_2)^{-1} \in H$. Therefore, $aHa^{-1} \subseteq H.$

(d) implies (e):

We have to show that all elements H can be expressed as $ah'a^{-1}$. For all $x \in H$, $ x= a(a^{-1}xa)a^{-1}$. $(a^{-1}xa) \in H$ from (d) by letting $a = a^{-1}$. Hence , $H \subseteq aHa^{-1}$. Together with (d), $aHa^{-1} = H$.

(e) implies (f):

$aHa^{-1} = H$ hence $aH = Ha$ by multiplying a on the right.

(f) implies (a):

NEED HELP.

Are my proof OK?

Comment: For the first one, you have an inclusion of left cosets. When can this happen?

Comment: I am not sure i really have no idea what the first statement is used for. I thought coset is to be defined. But here I have to prove it. So I really have no idea

Comment: Before coming to an exercise like this, you have probably already seen some basic properties of cosets, such as those needed for Lagrange's index theorem.

Comment: yup but those are for normal subgroup. here it is not necessarily normal

Comment: No, the properties if cosets used for Lagrange are not at all special to normal subgroups (and Lagrange is not just a statement for normal subgroups).

Comment: ok so what property are you referring to here?

Comment: actually i don't quite understand what does aHbH is a left coset of H in G mean

Comment: Distinct left cosets have empty intersection. So if one is contained in the other, this tells you that...?

Comment: oh so here when it says aHbH is a left coset of H in G, i can view it as say cH so that the property that distinct coset has empty intersection which i know is true for aH = bH can also be applied here?

Comment: I always thought that a left coset must be of the form aH so forms like $aHa_1H...a_nH$ are also called left coset? How to generalise distinct coset has empty intersection to this form of coset?

Comment: No, left coset is precisely something of the form $aH$ with $a\in G$. The longer expression need not be a coset at all.

Comment: so it works here because the questions explicitly says that aHbH is a left coset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) implies (b):
You know that $(aH)(bH)$ is a left coset of $H$ in $G$, and it intersects non-trivial the left coset $abH$. If two left cosets intersect each other, they coincide, so you must have equality.

(f) implies (a):
I'll show that $(aH)(bH)$ is the left coset $abH$. Because $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, the set of all products of two elements in $H$, namely $HH$, is equal to $H$. Thus:

$$
(aH)(bH)\overset{(f)}=(aH)(Hb)=a(HH)b=aHb=a(Hb)\overset{(f)}=a(bH)=abH
$$

Edit: A sketch on how to prove that distinct cosets do not intersect. Let $aH,bH$ be two cosets, and suppose that they are distinct. Suppose (towards a contradiction) that they do intersect at some point $c\in aH \cap bH$.

By definition, we find some $h,k\in H$ such that $c=ah=bk$. Thus $b=ahk^{-1}$. Now let $x=bh^{\prime}$ be any element of $bH$. Then:
$$
x=bh^{\prime}=ahk^{-1}h^{\prime}
$$
and $hk^{-1}h^{\prime}$ is in $H$ as $H$ is a subgroup. Thus $x\in aH$, and we have the inclusion $bH \subseteq aH$. Similarly, one has that $a=bkh^{-1}$ and repeats the argument to prove that $aH \subseteq bH$

Comment: how do you know that it intersects the left coset abH?

Comment: proving aHbH is a left coset of H is to prove that aHbH = abH?

Comment: 1. You showed yourself that $abH$ is contained in $(aH)(bH)$, so their intersection is $abH$. 2.I don't understand your second question, could please you explain it?

Comment: how do i know that the other direction is guaranteed?

Comment: What direction?

Comment: i know it is the case for aH = bH but here it is aHbH = H. How to show that that fact generalised to aHbH = H?

Comment: the direction $H \subseteq aHbH$

Comment: You said (and illustrated) that you can prove that $abH \subseteq (aH)(bH)$ in you attempt to prove that (a) implies (b)

Comment: what i am asking is that how to prove that distinct coset has empty intersection, which you are using here. I know that distinct coset has no intersection for coset of the form aH = bH but I am not sure if it is true for the form aHbH = cH. That is what i am asking

Comment: I'll add it above in a couple of minutes